# CSS. Как поставить список в одну строку?

Tags: html, css, float

Вроде поставил float: left; но список не выравнивается по левому краю и не встает в одну линию

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #EABCBC;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  font: 1.6em arial;
  padding: auto;
}

.complex_list {
  background-color: #76DBE4;
}

.complex_list ul li {
  float: left;
}

.complex_list li {
  font: 0.75em arial;
  list-style: none;
}

.complex_list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF8604;
}

.complex_list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <h1>Стройка</h1>

  <ul class="complex_list">
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: вставьте редактируемый код, ну чтобы мы могли его запустить и посмотреть. а еще чтобы сразу скопировать его в ответ и исправить

Comment: я вроде вставлял, но, видимо, где-то ошибся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.complex_list ul li` — Это значит "все li внутри ul, который внутри complex_list". Селектор неправильный, должен быть `ul.complex_list li` — "все li внутри ul с классом complex_list" и заработает.

Но float: left предназначен для обтекания текста, а не для позиционирования.

Пробуйте `ul.complex_list { display: flex; }`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #169;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  font: 1.6em arial;
  padding: auto;
}

.complex_list {
  background-color: #2bd;
  padding: 4px;
}

ul.complex_list {
  display: flex;
}

.complex_list li {
  font: 0.75em arial;
  list-style: none;
}

.complex_list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 2px;
  color: #fff;
}

.complex_list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <h1>Стройка</h1>

  <ul class="complex_list">
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cтройка</a></li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: или для селектора `.complex_list li` добавьте `display: inline` так это еще и будет центрироваться. ну потому что у вас `text-align: center` наследуется от `div.header`

Comment: я в .complex_list li добавил display: inline-flex, но что-то он не центрируется

Comment: потом в ul.complex_list прописал text-align: center и все заработало)

Comment: @G_M flex надо задать родителю ( ul.complex_list ) а не дочерним li.

Answer (score 2):

у вас ошибка в селекторе `.complex_list ul li` вы пытаетесь применить стили к несуществующему элементу, селектор должен быть такого вида

```
.complex_list li {
    float: left;
}
```

хотя для этой задачи лучше использовать

```
.complex_list li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

либо такой вариант

```
.complex_list {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Всем спасибо)))